# How do I validate first 2 letter or numbers in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, validation

I need to validate a string to check if the first two characters in a string are numbers.

I tried using in numeric but still had the issue that I did not want to check the whole string only the first two characters..

Comment: _"but still had the issue that I did not want to check the whole string only the first to characters"_ - and what stopped you from researching such a trivial thing as "how do I get the first two characters from a string in PHP" ...? Please show a bit more actual effort, _before_ you ask. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1427878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply [get the first two characters of the string on their own](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), and validate *that*:

```
$str = "1234kjhgkdfkgjh";

$result = ctype_digit(substr($str, 0, 2));
var_dump($result);
```

demo: https://3v4l.org/C33ui.

Or you could use a Regular Expression, as per [robotiaga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75532171/5947043)

Comment: I think the preg match solution works better. When the string is `.1.b2example` it also returns true. So for your example there also needs some proper validation first

Comment: @Baracuda078 True, good point. I think using `is_int` would fix that - demo: https://3v4l.org/M5JN6 . I have updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry to say but that's also not working. The return type of `substr` is a `fasle|string` so you also get `false` in this case

Comment: @Baracuda078 my apologies, trying to rush too much. ctype_digit would do it. https://3v4l.org/C33ui

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a Regular Expression

```
$string = "12example";
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{2}/", $string)) {
    echo "The first two characters are numbers.";
} else {
    echo "The first two characters are not numbers.";
}
```

Comment: Live demo: https://3v4l.org/ImaD7